# DropDownListFor binding to model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net mvc and despite several searches can't get my head successfully around drop down lists in a view.

Specifically I'm creating a project that is entity framework code first.

I have a form that requires the user to optionally pick the Licence Type they have.

And help or assistance would be greatly appreciated. I'm looking to create a DropDownListFor helper in the view to enable the drop down list for LicenceType.

The GRCMember model section relating to licence type is:

```
public class GRCMember
{
    [Column(TypeName = "int")]
    public int? LicenceTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

The Licence Type Model is:

```
public class LicenceType
{
    public int LicenceTypeId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(150)]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar")]
    public String Type { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "bit")]
    public bool? Dormant { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GRCMember> GRCMembers { get; set; }
}
```

The associated Register View Model section is:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Licence Type")]
    public int? SelectedLicenceTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

The get controller method is:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    return View();
}
```

And finally the  drop down section of the view is:

```
@model GRCWebApp.Models.RegisterViewModel
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedLicenceTypeId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedLicenceTypeId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedLicenceTypeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Comment: A ViewModel is a representation of what is in your view. You don't have anything that represents your dropdownlist of licensetypes.  `DropDownListFor(m => m.whateverimsupposetobindto, Model.licenseTypes);`

Comment: You got to give us Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Give me a simple sample, I will try post code for you.

Comment: Ive stripped out the code to only show the related sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that you have two entities called Person and City. Then you would use a ViewModel in order to populate these two entities in a model as shown below:

**PersonViewModel:**

```
public Person Person { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<City> Cities { get; set; }
```

The controller of course returns the ViewModel:

**Controller:**

```
public ViewResult Create()
{
    PersonViewModel model = new PersonViewModel
    {
        Person = new Person (),
        Cities = repository.Cities.ToList()
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

You should pass the ViewModel to your View and then use the Dropdownlist as shown below:

**View:**

```
@model Project.WebUI.Models.PersonViewModel
...
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Person.City)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Person.City, new SelectList(Model.Cities, "CityID", "CityName"), "---- Select ----")
```

Comment: It's certainly starting to however I have an error on repository, it doesn't exist in the current context?

Comment: Repository is the DbContext, you should change it with yours. repository.Cities returns the City entity from data layer.

Comment: Thanks I've changed it and that produces the drop down list, however when viewed its smaller and not styled the same a a text box, can this be changed?

Comment: Your are welcome... Of course can be changed. The only thing you should do open "Inspect Element" feature of Firebug (or other net tools of the another web browser) and get the css properties. And then go to the css line(s) and change it according to the textbox's properties (i.e. border color, background color, height, padding, etc.). Please do not forget to make a copy the related css file before editing so that you might need to revert it. On the other hand, I sıuggest you using Bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks, I'm already using bootstrap so was a little surprised when it was different

Comment: Ive fixed the problem by amending the view to this  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GRCMember.LicenceTypeId, new SelectList(Model.LicenceTypes, "LicenceTypeId", "Type"), new { @class = "form-control" })

Comment: In same cases it is normal to see some kind of conflicts between the css and js files and in that case some tweaks would be needed :)