# Declaring IEnumerable within service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a IEnumerable DropDownListFor within my view model.
This was originally a nullable int that I have now converted.

However now I have an error in my post method for my form which I believe is from the Variable within my service used by the method.

the error is: Error 2   Argument 12: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'int?'

It is the LicenceType that I've changed to an IEnumerable and its section within the view model is:

```
public IEnumerable<LicenceType> LicenceTypes { get; set; }
```

The service code is:

```
public GRCMemberService(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
{
 db = dbContext;
}

public void CreateGRCMember(string firstName, string lastName, string address1, string address2, string city, string county, string postcode, string telephone, DateTime dateOfBirth, string dietary, string compLicenceNo , int? LicenceTypeId, string nOKFirstName, string nOKLastName, string nOKTelephone, int? relationshipTypeId, bool otherOrgsGRC, bool otherClubEvents, bool otherOrgsOutside, string userId)
{
var GRCMember = new GRCMember { FirstName = firstName, LastName = lastName, Address1 = address1, Address2 = address2, City = city, County = county, Postcode = postcode, Telephone = telephone, DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth, Dietary = dietary, CompLicenceNo = compLicenceNo, LicenceTypeId = LicenceTypeId, NOKFirstName = nOKFirstName, NOKLastName = nOKLastName, NOKTelephone= nOKTelephone, RelationshipTypeId = relationshipTypeId, OtherOrgsGRC = otherOrgsGRC, OtherClubEvents = otherClubEvents, OtherOrgsOutside = otherOrgsOutside, ApplicationUserId = userId };
db.GRCMember.Add(GRCMember);
db.SaveChanges();

}
```

The post method is:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                UserManager.AddClaim(user.Id, new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, model.FirstName));
                var service = new GRCMemberService(HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>());
                service.CreateGRCMember(model.FirstName, model.LastName, model.Address1, model.Address2, model.City, model.County, model.Postcode, model.Telephone, model.DateOfBirth, model.Dietary, model.CompLicenceNo, model.LicenceTypes, model.NOKFirstName, model.NOKLastName, model.NOKTelephone, model.RelationshipTypeId, model.OtherOrgsGRC, model.OtherClubEvents, model.OtherOrgsOutside, user.Id);

                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: And what the error is?

Comment: That would help wouldn't it, I've edited the question

Comment: service.CreateGRCMember exepects an Nullable<int> and you are passing an IEnumerable<LicenseType> to it, how do you expect that work?

Comment: I don't, but I don't know what to replace it with I'm afraid

Comment: You should start from "why you changed the type to IEnumerable<LicenseType>?"

Comment: Can you add the code of `RegisterViewModel` ?

Comment: The following post shows why I changed it to a IEnumerable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738850/dropdownlistfor-binding-to-model it was because I wanted a drop down list for the Licence Type. The first snippet of code above is the section within the view model. There

Comment: You have `LicenseTypes` which is a collection, but you need to pass a single id. Which one do you want to pass? You need something like a `SelectedLicense` that you can populate with which ever `LicenseType` you want to pass to `CreateGRCMember` and in the call to `CreateGRCMember` pass something like `SelectedLicense.Id` (or whatever the id property of `LicenseType` is).

Comment: Ive amended the view model to this [Display(Name = "Licence Type")]
        public int? SelectedLicenceTypeId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<LicenceType> LicenceTypes { get; set; }

Comment: How to I then map the chosen Licence Type Id to this?

Comment: the view code for the drop down is currently this                                         @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GRCMember.LicenceTypeId, new SelectList(Model.LicenceTypes, "LicenceTypeId", "Type"), new { @class = "form-control" })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help and bearing with me, this was no doubt a week 1 day 1 problem but thankfully your patience has help solve it.

Ive ameneded the view model to:

```
[Display(Name = "Licence Type")]
    public int? SelectedLicenceTypeId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<LicenceType> LicenceTypes { get; set; }
```

The Post Method to:

```
     [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                UserManager.AddClaim(user.Id, new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, model.FirstName));
                var service = new GRCMemberService(HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>());
                service.CreateGRCMember(model.FirstName, model.LastName, model.Address1, model.Address2, model.City, model.County, model.Postcode, model.Telephone, model.DateOfBirth, model.Dietary, model.CompLicenceNo, model.SelectedLicenceTypeId, model.NOKFirstName, model.NOKLastName, model.NOKTelephone, model.RelationshipTypeId, model.OtherOrgsGRC, model.OtherClubEvents, model.OtherOrgsOutside, user.Id);
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

The service to:

```
        public void CreateGRCMember(string firstName, string lastName, string address1, string address2, string city, string county, string postcode, string telephone, DateTime dateOfBirth, string dietary, string compLicenceNo , int? LicenceTypeId,  string nOKFirstName, string nOKLastName, string nOKTelephone, int? relationshipTypeId, bool otherOrgsGRC, bool otherClubEvents, bool otherOrgsOutside,  string userId)
    {
        var GRCMember = new GRCMember { FirstName = firstName, LastName = lastName, Address1 = address1, Address2 = address2, City = city, County = county, Postcode = postcode, Telephone = telephone, DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth, Dietary = dietary, CompLicenceNo = compLicenceNo, LicenceTypeId = LicenceTypeId, NOKFirstName = nOKFirstName, NOKLastName = nOKLastName, NOKTelephone= nOKTelephone, RelationshipTypeId = relationshipTypeId, OtherOrgsGRC = otherOrgsGRC, OtherClubEvents = otherClubEvents, OtherOrgsOutside = otherOrgsOutside,  ApplicationUserId = userId };
        db.GRCMember.Add(GRCMember);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

And the view to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLicenceTypeId, new SelectList(Model.LicenceTypes, "LicenceTypeId", "Type"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Thanks all